# I get corrupted MS Excel file with Apache POI on Atlassian JIRA

Tags: java, excel, jira-plugin

I get corrupted MS Excel file with Apache POI on Atlassian JIRA.

I think this possible JVM memory error.

I have JDK 1.7.0_75 but is not supports enoung JVM maximun memory.

Where I find Oracle Java SDK that supports JVM maximun memory up to 1024 Mb?

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: If you want help, I suggest posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (with emphasis on *M*).

Comment: I edited it now to minimal.

Comment: The "E" stands for example, which you now seem to have removed? I am not sure if there is now enough information in your question to post any sort of answer, since it's also unclear as to what you are asking.

Comment: _I will try to edit it more clear asap.